# get name of checkbox in gwt java

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox

When I create a table from an array, I fill ithe first column with the values present in the array, with the second column being ckeckBoxes with the values of the index of the array. I would need to retrieve the name of the selected checkBox. Below is my code, could anyone help me please?

Thanks for your help!

```
public class AddDoodlePart3 extends Composite {

MainView main = new MainView();
FlexTable table= new FlexTable();
VerticalPanel ab = new VerticalPanel();
HorizontalPanel hor = new HorizontalPanel();
InlineLabel lb = new InlineLabel("tette");
CheckBox ck ;
TextBox orario = new TextBox();
Button btn = new Button("Inserisci");
int culo;

public AddDoodlePart3(String det, ArrayList<String> listDate){
    initWidget(this.ab);
    this.ab.add(lb);
    System.out.println(det+listDate.size());
    table.setText(0, 0, " ");
    table.setText(0, 1, "Opzione");
    table.setText(0, 2, " ");
    System.out.println("1");

    for(int i=0;i<listDate.size();i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        this.ck = new CheckBox(""+i);
        table.setWidget(i, 0, ck);

        table.setText(i, 1, listDate.get(i));
        ck.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

              boolean checked = ((CheckBox) event.getSource()).getValue();
              Window.alert("It is " + (checked ? "" : "not ") + "checked "+ culo);
            }
          });
    }

    this.ab.add(table);
    this.hor.add(orario);
    this.hor.add(btn);
    this.ab.add(hor);
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        //  System.out.println(culo);


        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a DataGrid widget for these purposes. See [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) for an example. Click on a Source Code link to see how to implement this DataGrid.

You can set a SelectionModel on a DataGrid - in your case you need a MultiSelectionModel. Then, getting the list of selected items is as easy as:

```
selectionModel.getSelectedSet();
```